# Grouping based on an id and specific timeframe taken from multiple columns, and converting to long format

Tags: r

Using the example dataset, the summary for this problem is for each id, for each in_visit within id, create a unique id_2 for all out_visit instances that are within 365 days prior of in_visit date.
In the example dataset for id=1, there is a single in_visit date, but multiple out_visit dates. Each out_visit date may (or may not) have codes in one of the 4 columns c1 - c4. No codes appear for in_visit dates.
I would like to format this data to long format such that all of the codes that correspond to out_visits within 365 days prior to the in_visit, are put into a single column, and assigned a unique id_2.
When there is more than a single in_visit date, as for id=2, then some codes in the c1 - c4 columns may be duplicated since they may be 365 days prior to more than a single in_visit.
For example, the data for id=2, out_visit=10/6/2020, would appear twice for the same id but have two different id_2 values, in the final dataset.
Thus, for every in_visit date for each id that has an in_visit date, there would be a unique id_2 for the final dataset. But, these might share some of the same data from columns c1-c4.
I have tried to several methods but could not seem to create the unique id_2.

```
#initial dataset
ID <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3",
        "3","3","3","3","3","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","5","5","6")
out_visit <- c("","2021-03-25","2021-06-01","2021-01-01","2020-10-02",
               "2020-09-12","2020-02-06","","2021-04-25","2021-06-01","",
               "2021-01-01","2020-10-06","","2020-09-12","2019-02-06","",
               "2021-04-02","2021-08-01","2021-01-01","2020-10-02","2020-09-12",
               "2020-02-06","","2014-03-25","2015-06-01","2014-01-01","2018-10-02",
               "2014-09-12","2019-02-06","2020-06-05","2020-06-24","")
in_visit <- c("2021-03-17","","","","","","","2021-03-01","","","2020-11-02","",
              "","2020-09-12","","","2017-08-03","","","","","","","2021-03-17",
              "","","","","","","","","2021-02-02")
c1 <- c("","e23","e45","d55","r44","","r44","","e23","e45","","d55","r44","","",
        "r44","","e23","r44","q22","r44","w3","r44","","y6","i88","","r44","",
        "u77","y66","u77","")
c2 <- c("","","d44","c33","t55","","","","","d44","","c33","t55","","","","",
        "e24","d44","c33","t55","","","","","","","","","","","","")
c3 <- c("","","","e22","y55","","","","","","","e22","y55","","","","","e25","",
        "e22","y55","","","","","","","","","","","","")
c4 <- c("","","","","y66","","","","","","","","y66","","","","","e26","","e23",
        "y66","","","","","","","","","","","","")
df1 <- data.frame(ID,out_visit,in_visit,c1,c2,c3,c4)
```

```
#final dataset
ID <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2",
        "2","3","4","6")
ID_2 <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3",
          "3","4","5","6","7")
date <- c("2021-03-17","2021-03-17","2021-03-17","2021-03-17","2021-03-17",
          "2021-03-17","2021-03-17","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01",
          "2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2021-03-01","2020-11-02",
          "2020-11-02","2020-11-02","2020-11-02","2020-09-12","2017-08-03",
          "2021-03-17","2021-02-02")
code <- c("d55","c33","e22","r44","t55","y55","y66","d55","c33","e22","r44",
          "t55","y55","y66","r44","t55","y55","y66","","","","")

df2 <- data.frame(ID,ID_2,date,code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this captures what you are looking for, but hope this may be helpful. I wrote this out using additional steps initially for clarity.

I separated your `in_visit` information from `out_visit` with its associated codes (c1-c4); now they are in two data.frames.

The `in_visit` data.frame can have a date range (`in_visit` date and the date - 365 days).

The `out_visit` data.frame is put into long form with `pivot_longer`.

Then, using `fuzzy_left_join` from the `fuzzyjoin` package, you can join the two data.frames based on the `ID` and `out_visit` dates that fit within your `in_visit` date range.

A separate `id_2` was created based on unique `out_visit` dates for a given `ID`. It was unclear if multiple `out_visit` could exist for a given `ID`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(data.table)

in_df1 <- df1 %>%
  filter(in_visit != "") %>%
  mutate(in_visit = as.Date(in_visit)) %>%
  mutate(in_visit_365 = in_visit - 365) %>%
  select(ID, in_visit, in_visit_365)
  
out_df1 <- df1 %>%
  filter(out_visit != "") %>%
  select(-in_visit) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("c")) %>%
  filter(value != "")

fuzzy_left_join(
  in_df1,
  out_df1,
  by = c("ID" = "ID", "in_visit" = "out_visit", "in_visit_365" = "out_visit"),
  match_fun = c(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)
) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(id_2 = rleid(ID.x, in_visit)) %>%
  select(ID.x, id_2, in_visit, value)
```

**Output**

```
   ID.x id_2   in_visit value
1     1    1 2021-03-17   d55
2     1    1 2021-03-17   c33
3     1    1 2021-03-17   e22
4     1    1 2021-03-17   r44
5     1    1 2021-03-17   t55
6     1    1 2021-03-17   y55
7     1    1 2021-03-17   y66
8     2    2 2021-03-01   d55
9     2    2 2021-03-01   c33
10    2    2 2021-03-01   e22
11    2    2 2021-03-01   r44
12    2    2 2021-03-01   t55
13    2    2 2021-03-01   y55
14    2    2 2021-03-01   y66
15    2    3 2020-11-02   r44
16    2    3 2020-11-02   t55
17    2    3 2020-11-02   y55
18    2    3 2020-11-02   y66
```

**Edit**: Here is a `data.table` alternative that might work faster. This would substitute for the `fuzzy_left_join`.

```
setDT(in_df1, ID)
setDT(out_df1, ID)

out_df1$out_visit <- as.Date(out_df1$out_visit)

out_df1[in_df1, 
        .(ID, out_visit, value), 
        on = .(ID, out_visit <= in_visit,  out_visit >= in_visit_365), 
        nomatch = 0L][
  , ID_2 := rleid(ID, out_visit)][]
```

**Output**

```
    ID  out_visit value ID_2
 1:  1 2021-03-17   d55    1
 2:  1 2021-03-17   c33    1
 3:  1 2021-03-17   e22    1
 4:  1 2021-03-17   r44    1
 5:  1 2021-03-17   t55    1
 6:  1 2021-03-17   y55    1
 7:  1 2021-03-17   y66    1
 8:  2 2021-03-01   d55    2
 9:  2 2021-03-01   c33    2
10:  2 2021-03-01   e22    2
11:  2 2021-03-01   r44    2
12:  2 2021-03-01   t55    2
13:  2 2021-03-01   y55    2
14:  2 2021-03-01   y66    2
15:  2 2020-11-02   r44    3
16:  2 2020-11-02   t55    3
17:  2 2020-11-02   y55    3
18:  2 2020-11-02   y66    3
```

Comment: I do have a question for you. The solution works great but it tends to use up a great amount of memory. I am running this for around 5 million observations. Do you have suggestions for making this more efficient?

Comment: Is the join operation take a long time? Perhaps a complete `data.table` solution might work better for a large amount of observations? Would you be interested in that? If so, I could edit the answer later on with an alternative.

Comment: Yes, it's slated to take around 2 days. An alternative would be great!

Comment: @TexasMed Please see edited answer for `data.table` alternative - hope this gives you a similar result (and is faster).